# What changes to Blinding Barrage, as reflected in the October 2011 errata updates, actually happened?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, errata

Listed [here](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/updates) it states the *Blinding Barrage* has had it's damage reduced. On the [errata for the Player's Handbook](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/UpdatePH.pdf) (page 8) as of the October update it states that:

*Blinding Barrage*
Page 119: Delete “2[W] + “ from the Hit entry, and
replace “Half ” with “Dexterity modifier” in the Miss
entry.

So my question is as follows: **What does *Blinding Barrage* actually do now as of the October 2011 errata update?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It now does a lot less damage,

From the [compendium](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=163):

> **Hit**: Dexterity modifier damage, and the target is blinded until the end of your next turn.
>
> **Miss**: Dexterity modifier damage.